# How can I change this filter from a specific AD Group to All AD Groups in the Organization?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, activedirectorymembership

This filterString gets all AD users from a specific AD group, I need to change this to get ALL users from ALL groups in my organization. I have read through dozens of similar questions and changed this string around several times and cannot find the solution.

```
  String filterString = "(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=cn=" + this.ldapUserSearch + ",ou=Groups,OU=Organization,dc=organizationsoftware,dc=com))";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following filter, which includes an [attribute presence clause](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Presence%20SearchFilter):

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=*))
```

This will return every user whose `memberOf` attribute is set to any value. This should have the effect of retrieving all users from all groups.